# Remove a Guid(uuid) from a nested list via Mongo DB C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB Model which consists of an Id(Guid) and a list of Ids (which are also Guids). Now... for some reason I want to query the list of UserIds and if there is an element with a certain Guid I want to remove it from my Mongo Array.

So here's a part of my model:

```
public class Model {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("userIds")]
        public List<Guid> UserIds{ get; set; }
}
```

and here's the piece of code from the repository where the list of Guids should get an element removed.

```
var filter = Builders<Models.Event>.Filter.Eq(m => m.Id, someId);
var update = Builders<Models.Event>.Update.PullFilter(m => m.UserIds,
                                                i => i == userId);

await _events.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update);
```

In theory, this should work... The problem is Mongo keeps giving me the following error:

```
"error": "{document} is not supported.",
```

For some reason, my PullFilter doesn't seem to be able to identify my Guid in the DB.

Here's how the Guid is stored in the DB:

```
userIds:Array
0:Binary('WYsLZis0RkOeiQ1RNyjzGw==', 3)
```

Is this a conversion issue? Should I use a string instead of a Guid here? I can't figure out exactly what's happening behind the scenes and why this wouldn't work.

I also tried altering the code to have the Guid be converted to string and check the value against my userId.ToString() but then, i get `{document}.ToString() is not supported`.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: You should have more error information than what you provided. Given what you did provide, I have no idea what the error/problem even is.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for it? I think the problem here is that MongoDB.Driver cannot translate `i => i == userId` this filter into a meaningful mongodb filter

Comment: I am still trying to figure what exactly is the problem but with no progress so far.

I did a workaround for the time being which is to wrap this Guid property with a parent class so I can filter using a propertyName

if anyone stuck what I did is

`public class ParentObject
{
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}`

and the filter will be:
`var filter = Builders<Models.Event>.Filter.Eq(m => m.Id, someId);
var update = Builders<Models.Event>.Update.PullFilter(m => m.ParentObjectPropertyName,
                    Builders<ParentObject>.Filter.Where(s => s.UserId == userId));`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this instead of your update definition:

`var update = Builders<Models.Event>.Update.Pull(m => m.UserIds, userId);`